# How to add line numbers and highlighted the line which is clicked in textarea using ReactJS and pure javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make a project like (https://pretty-print-json.js.org/) using react js and tailwind CSS.
And I became able to just minify and formatted the JSON data. My project live site (https://json-formatter-eta.vercel.app/)

Now, I have 3 questions.
1 - How can I add line numbers in the text area?
2 - How can I highlight the line which is clicked by the user to edit?
3 - How can I format the text color depending on the key-value? I mean key should have one color and the value should have another color.

Is it possible by using textarea? Or do I have to use content editable div? If I have to use content editable div then how it could be possible to get the value of the div(because if I use innerHTML to get the value of the div it replaces the space with   and then it would not be possible to format the JSON file.)

All I have to done by using pure javascript. Could you anyone help me to done my project please?

Comment: If you check the sample project linked, the output is made using spans and lists. And the usage of these tags changes dynamically,

Comment: sorry bro, could you explain more?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.